# How to remove negative Zeros from c++ codes?

Tags: c++, macros, negative-zero

How to remove "negative zero" in c/c++?
I am trying this-

```
#define isEq(a, b) ((abs(a-b)<EPS) ? 1 : 0)
#define NegZero(x) (x = isEq(x, -0.0) ? 0 : x)
```

Is it okay and safe?
or
is there any other easy and safe way?
Specially for contest coding.
please help....

Comment: How about `x == 0 && signbit(x)`?

Comment: Is it safe? No, since it's a macro. If you want safe, use an inline function.

Comment: There is no language C/C++! Pick one.

Comment: It might help to know *why* you want to remove them. Can you give an example of a problem you're getting, where the solution would be to turn a negative zero into a positive one? For the time being, I'd just write `static inline NegZero(double x) { if (x == 0.0) { return 0.0; } else { return x; } }`, because AFAIK, `-0.0 == +0.0` must always be true in C and C++.

Comment: @Olaf: `EPS` probably stands for "*Epsilon*", which by convention identifies a (typically small) value which defines a thresh hold for a difference for example, a limit in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit

Comment: @alk: I anticipated that. But that would be different, depending for `float`, `double` and `long double`.

Comment: Why? Appropriate casting could be applied by the compiler. @Olaf

Comment: The bug in the code is the usage of `abs()` which returns `int`.

Comment: @alk: And the compiler would also use the correct value? Note this depends on the type of the argument."epsilon" is a well-defined term in float context. That's why I asked OP to clarify.

Comment: However, as it stands, this all does not make sense (see my last comment). At least not for `EPS` being `>-1` and `<1`.

Comment: @Rhymoid I am trying to solve [this problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=394) and my code is [here](http://ideone.com/47Pnvv). this code is giving -0.0 for some inputs like `-1.4 8.8 1.4 7.1 8.8 7.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you posted in your comments, your approach seems correct: your answer is a negative number that is very close to zero, and because you're rounding it to three digits (using `printf("... %.3lf ...", ...)`), it looks like `-0.000`. Your approach (check if it's close to `0.0` using `abs(a - b) < epsilon`; if it is, use `0.0`, otherwise use the value itself) is mostly correct, except for the issue that macros aren't exactly a good fit.

Rather than writing

```
printf("(%.3lf,%.3lf)\n", I1.x, I1.y);
```

I would suggest using something like

```
printf(
    "(%.3lf,%.3lf)\n",
    NegZero(I1.x),
    NegZero(I1.y)
);
```

and define (although I'd pick different names)

```
static inline bool isEq(double x, double y) {
    return abs(x, y) < EPS;
}

static inline NegZero(double x) {
    if (isEq(x, 0.0)) {
        return 0.0;
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

(The reason for the confused comments is that there actually is something called negative zero in IEEE floating point arithmetic. If that were the case, the suggested solutions would have worked.)